# How to determine which image triggered a macro

Tags: excel, vba

In excel, I can assign a macro to an image, with this dialog:

[image]

This results in the code:

```
Private Sub MyShape_Click()
    ' ...
End Sub
```

However, I will need to assign this macro to many different images.  How can I determine which image was selected from inside my click handler, and how do I get a reference to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Assign the same macro to all your pictures and use [`Application.Caller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687.aspx) in your macro to determine the picture/shape that called it. In this case (picture/shape) `Application.Caller` will be of type `String`.

```vb
Private Sub GenericPicture_Click()
    Select Case Application.Caller
        Case "Picture 1"
            'do your work
            MsgBox "You got me"
        Case "Picture 2" 
            'do your work
        ...

    End Select 

    'Lets flip the picture that has been clicked
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
        .Flip msoFlipHorizontal
    End With
End Sub
```

And you might also implement required behavior calling a sub, which implements needed processing logic, with a parameter from separate macros:

```
Sub Picture1_Click()
    DoWork 1
End Sub

Sub Picture2_Click()
    DoWork 2
End Sub

Sub DoWork(ByVal pic As Integer)
    'Implement your logic here
    MsgBox "Hi! I am picture" & pic
End Sub
```

Where `Picture1_Click()` and `Picture2_Click()` are macros that you assign to your images/shapes.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a little, but...how can I get a reference back to the image? This only gives me a name.   The thing I'm really after is to get a reference back to the original image so I can programmatically CHANGE the image.

Comment: You get your ref by using `Shapes` collection and `Application.Caller` like this `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)`. And then do with it whatever the object model allows you. See updated answer for flipping the clicked picture.

Comment: @notfed Do you need more help with the question?

Comment: Thank you so much so far!  Yeah, I can flip the image, which works!  But, how do I change its image?  I have a `Picture` object that I want to set it to.  How do I assign to it?  I don't see a ".Picture" or ".Image" property or method.

Comment: And `.Fill.UserPicture` only lets you load it from a file location.  I want to assign it from a `Picture` object .

Comment: Well this is a subject for a totally different question. My understanding is that you either `.Fill.UserPicture` or you `Delete` and `AddPicture` (unfortunately both only from file) and bind it to your macro with `OnAction`. As an alternative to adding pictures from files you might consider using `Duplicate` on existing shapes. That way you can add all necessary pictures beforehand make them invisible and duplicate and position as needed.